# How do I map elements from mapped parent type?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, typescript-generics

This is a more advanced follow up to [how to map types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76403272/6893866), I have a collection of parameterized types that I would like to map to a friendlier layout, but the mapped type doesn't seem to have a method to refer to a sub element of a type, or it's parameter type. How do I type the remapping so that I still have the type from the parent type?

Below is a simple, minimal example of what I am trying to do.

```
class Action<P> {
  can(value: P): boolean {
    //stuff
    return true;
  }
  do(value: P): boolean {
    //stuff
    return true;
  }
}

const actionSet = {
  increment: new Action<string>(),
  foo: new Action<Date>(),
  baz: new Action<boolean>(),
}

function helper(actions: {[k: string]: Action<any>}) {
  const set = {
        can: {} as any, //?
        do: {} as any, //?
    }

    for (const key in actions) {
        set.can[key] = actions[key].can
        set.do[key] = actions[key].do
    }

    return set;
}
const friendlyActions = helper(actionSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out mapped types can access sub items. I was close, just doing it wrong. The sub types can be accessed by index.

The answer for the original example is the following.

```
/**
 * Creates a helper object from an action set.
 * @param actionSet - The action set to create the helper from.
 * @returns The helper object.
 */
export function createHelper<T extends Record<string, Action<any>>>(actionSet: T): { can: { [K in keyof T]: T[K]['can'] }, do: { [K in keyof T]: T[K]['do'] } } {
  const set = {
    can: {} as { [K in keyof T]: T[K]['can'] },
    do: {} as { [K in keyof T]: T[K]['do'] }
  };

  for (const key in actionSet) {
    set.can[key] = actionSet[key].can;
    set.do[key] = actionSet[key].do;
  }

  return set;
}
```